# Determining the "current_page" in WordPress Custom Menus

Tags: menus, css

I am using WordPress [Custom Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). I have links like

- **Home** - Rendered using `home.php`
- **Blog** - Rendered using `page-blog.php` with `WP_Query` to get blog posts
- **Services** - Page
- **Portfolio** - Rendered using `page-portfolio.php` to get all posts of the Custom Post Type "Portfolio"
- **Contact** - Page

I will like to determine which link is current and style them. How will I do that? WordPress wont know which is selected when I am in a simple blog post for example `single.php`

Comment: `.current-menu-item` ?

Comment: @One Trick Pony, yes but that wont work when I am in a single post page for example?

Comment: You want blog to show when on a single post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for category:

- li.current-category-ancestor
- li.current-cat

for menu:

- li.current-menu-item

for page:

- li.current_page_item
- li.current-page-ancestor

for post:

- li.current-post-ancestor

For more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dynamic_Menu_Highlighting